# Best practices for apps with many fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I find a lot of information about how to add or replace a fragment, but very little information on best practices of when to do each, or whether show and hide are worth the extra trouble of using them.

I have an app with 15+ fragments, a view pager, a drawer....for testing purposes everything is working ok, but it all falls apart in real world usage. When I replace fragments instead of using add, the backstack seems to get all messed up after a while. For example, if I do something like:

(A) List Fragment -> (B) Detail View -> (C) Add comment

Going from A->B->C works fine. If I hit back in C I go back to B, if I go back to C after that everything seems fine, but when I hit back again A loads on top of B. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but none of the tutorials really go into depth about this stuff.

If I use add instead of replace the workflow is correct, but I have a host of other problems.  My view pager remains active under model detail fragments, ActionBar titles get set when a fragment is first loaded, but when you hit back I don't know of a method that fires letting a fragment know it's the one being displayed, so I can't reset the ActionBar title, or change the state of the up button.

Is there a tutorial about managing fragments in large apps? Something beyond just how to load a fragment?

Comment: Sounds like a more iterative testing approach would have helped find issues earlier on in the process (then you could give a sample of code in a question and have us help). As it is, this isn't a solvable question.

Comment: Also: You don't have to use only fragments for everything: sometimes multiple activities is the best way to transition between totally different screens.

Comment: I'm actually currently transitioning away from having many activities. I have my own reasons for that which aren't really relevant here.

I could provide code, but I'm not too sure of what, the code to add/replace fragments is pretty standard, I'm overriding onBackPressed, but am pretty much just calling popBackStack in it.

There isn't much that I'm doing that weird or outside of the norm, so I wouldn't know what code to post. I'm really just asking about a more "real world" tutorial on using fragments. Something beyond the "here's how to load a fragment" that is so common.